# What is the verb and subject of this question?

Tags: subjects

So here is a question:

> What is Apple's stock price?

First: Is this a full question, or would we need to add something like: *What is Apple's stock price at the moment?*

Second: What is the subject and verb of the question? Is the subject "Apple's stock" and the verb price, or is "Apple's stock price" the subject? I'm confused.

Comment: The verb is "is" (as in "to be"), the subject is "price", "Apple's" and "stock" are modifying "price".

Comment: You may be interested in [this tool](http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/submit-sentence-4.html). (It takes a little getting used to.)

Answer (score 2):

The verb *to be* is a copula here. With copulae, we usually analyse the first constitutent as the subject, the second one as the subject complement.

- *What* = subject
- *is* = main verb
- *Apple's stock price* = subject complement

Within the noun phrase *Apple's stock price*, the word *price* is the head; *stock* modifies *price*; and *Apple's* modifies *stock price*.

Your "at the moment" is possible, but unnecessary, because it is assumed either way.